# How to generate insert SQL statement in excel with other records

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have some data shown in the below picture. I also have an insert SQL statement extracted from database.

How can I write insert SQL statement so that I can include other records as well?

[enter image description here][1]

```
INSERT INTO "tblcompany" ("fldComID", "fldComCode", "fldComName", "fldComChiName", "fldComTaxNo", "fldMPFMemberID", "fldCreateDate", "fldCreateEmpName", "fldLastMDate", "fldLastMEmpName") 
VALUES (1, 'Code 1', 'Company 1', 'Company Chi. 1', '1D1-20978121', 'MPFMemberID 1', '2020-06-12 09:52:27.000', 'E001', '2020-06-12 09:52:27.000', 'E001');
```

Comment: fldComID  fldComCode Company Name Company Chi. Name Tax Return File 
17          Code 17             ABC123                     1公司                    6B1-904 
18          Code 18             ABC124                     2公司                    6F1-90440

Comment: Where are the other records that you want to insert?  Are those records in another table?

Comment: You put the word "excel" in your question title. What does this question have to do with Excel?

Comment: Also, your image hasn't been posted

Answer (score 0):

You're image isn't showing up, so I'm guessing at what you want here.

If you're asking how to input a bunch of data from excel into a table, then I would recommend converting file to csv and using psql if supported and you have thousands of records. You'll need a machine that supports it, log into that machine via a command prompt and run these two rows. Replace all bracketed values with your names and remove the brackets.

```
    \psql -h [myserver.address.com] -d [database_name] -U [user_name]
    \copy [my_table_name_on_database] from '[my_csv_file.csv]' csv header delimiter ','
```

But if you're old fashioned and just looking to manually insert a few rows from excel into a database table, then here's the format of the formula you want to write in excel. In this sample, using an excel data with 4 columns. The first column is numeric, while the others are strings.

So, excel data looks like this:

```
    fldComID    fldComCode  fldComName  fldComChiName
    1   Code_1  Company1    CompanyChi.g
    2   Code_x  Company2    CompanyChi.me
    3   Code_44 Company3    CompanyChi.u
```

In column E, place this formula:
=CONCAT("(",A2,", '",B2,"', '",C2,"', '",D2,"'),")

The output will look like this:

```
    (1, 'Code_1', 'Company1', 'CompanyChi.g'),
    (2, 'Code_x', 'Company2', 'CompanyChi.me'),
    (3, 'Code_44', 'Company3', 'CompanyChi.u'),
```

So, you're insert statement will just be:

```
    insert into my_table values
    (1, 'Code_1', 'Company1', 'CompanyChi.g'),
    (2, 'Code_x', 'Company2', 'CompanyChi.me'),
    (3, 'Code_44', 'Company3', 'CompanyChi.u')
```

You just need to repeat the formula pattern for each additional column you want to include. Ticks are needed for varchar columns, otherwise leave out for integer/numeric columns.